# Brightness up/down keys don't work

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, brightness

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an ASUS Z450LA laptop, that has Intel HD5500 integrated graphics.

The brightness up/down keys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd>) don't work; however, if I use my desktop environment to control the brightness, it works, however is annoying to not have the easy way to control brightness.

When I use `xev`, it shows that these keys are not generating events; it's as if the system doesn't detect them at all.

What to do?

The content of `/sys/class/backlight`:

```
/sys/class/backlight$ ls
intel_backlight
```

and within the `intel_backlight` directory, has:

```
actual_brightness
bl_power
brightness
device -> ../../card0-eDP-1
max_brightness
power
subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
type
uevent
```

Comment: What is the content of `/sys/class/backlight/` (probably something like `acpi_video0`, and then what is the content of that).  There should be at least some ACPI info there since you are able to change the screen brightness.

Comment: @grochmal I added the contents of this directory to my question.

Comment: hmm... normally, it is the other way around, the OS has problems to find the `intel` controls.  Just to make sure, you have `acpi` and `dpms` in `lsmod` (i.e. modules are loaded).  And a curious debug question, when you are within the GRUB menu (before selecting the boot options) does the keys work?

Comment: @grochmal in the GRUB menu the keys don't work. I don't have any `dpms` module and with `acpi` I have the modules `snd_soc_sst_acpi`, `acpi_thermal_rel`, `acpi_pad`, `sdhci_acpi` and `sdhci`.

Comment: I'd argue that these keys use some very specific hook that comes with some very specific driver.  If you have xorg running, and some ACPI present that's probably as far as you can get.  `xev` should identify `F5` as 72 and `F6` as 73, that's what happens I believe.  Now, on a machine that I have similar keys (but with an ATI card, not intel) `xev` generates 232 keycode for `Fn+F5` and 233 for `Fn+F6`.  Funny enough, `xev` identifies all combinations of `Fn+<key>` on that machine, even if there is no assigned function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the keys aren't working but, I have something useful to share.

As mentioned, you are using Ubuntu 16.04 and so this will work definitely for you.

[Brightness-Controller](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/05/install-brightness-controller-utility-in-ubuntu-16-04-higher/)